# Does it seem right to calculate fractional powers by walking steps method?

Tags: math, logarithm, arithmetic-expressions, exponent

We know that **x^y** means **x** multiplied by itself **y** times or **x** taking **y** steps.

Is this method suitable when **y** (the power) is **fractional**.

**e.g.**
if **x** = **2** and **y** = **3.5**,
we would have
**2^3.5** = (2 x 1) x (2 x 1) x (2 x 1) x (2 x 0.5) = 2 x 2 x 2 x 1 = **8**

The result is
**2^3** = **2^3.5** (not possible)

I can't get the reason for it being the wrong method of calculating fractional powers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to math.stackexchange.com, but the short answer is that n^(0.5) is equal to √n, not n×0.5. So for example 2^3.5 = 8 × √2

Comment: 2^3.5 = 2^1 * 2^1 * 2^1 * 2^0.5 is correct. 2^1 is only coincidentally equal to 2*1, but 2^0.5 is not equal to 2*0.5, it is sqrt(2).